# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы с массива и вывести их на экран

Tags: java, массивы

Массив не сортированный, вбивается с клавиатуры. Вписываются только положительные числа, но, когда вбиваешь любое отрицательное число, происходит вывод массива на экран без дубликатов.

Допустим есть
0 15 15 5 0 10 25 5 0 0 5 15 10 40 10 30 -2

Результат должен быть:
0 15 5 10 25 40 30

Необязательно, чтобы был сортированным.

Всё кроме удаление элементов, я сделал вот что:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] mas = new int[50];

        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        mas[0] = inputInt;

        int count = 1;
        while(inputInt > 0) {
            inputInt = scanner.nextInt();
            if(inputInt > 0)
                mas[count++] = inputInt;
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting now.");
        scanner.close();



        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print(mas[i]+" ");
        }



    }
```

П.с. без использования коллекции.

Comment: Допускается использование Set<Integer> или преобразование массива в Set<Integer>?

Comment: нет, у меня задание про использование простых массивов. Без коллекций, сетов и т.д.

Comment: Наивный способ - это пробегать весь массив при добавлении и искать элементы. Если такой уже есть - не добавлять. Способ очень медленный по времени на больших массивах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение примерно такое

```
public class Main {

        private static void removeDuplicates(int[] arrayWithDuplicates) {
            System.out.println("Массив с дубликатами: ");

            for (int arrayWithDuplicate : arrayWithDuplicates) {
                System.out.print(arrayWithDuplicate + "\t");
            }
            int noOfUniqueElements = arrayWithDuplicates.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfUniqueElements; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < noOfUniqueElements; j++) {

                    if(arrayWithDuplicates[i] == arrayWithDuplicates[j]) {
                        arrayWithDuplicates[j] = arrayWithDuplicates[noOfUniqueElements-1];
                        noOfUniqueElements--;
                        j--;
                    }
                }
            }

            int[] arrayWithoutDuplicates = Arrays.copyOf(arrayWithDuplicates, noOfUniqueElements);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Массив без дубликатов: ");
            for (int arrayWithoutDuplicate : arrayWithoutDuplicates) {
                System.out.print(arrayWithoutDuplicate + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("==============================");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            removeDuplicates(new int[] {0, 15, 15, 5, 0, 10, 25, 5, 0, 0, 5, 15, 10, 40, 10, 30, -2});
        }
    }
```

Вывод будет

```
0   15  40  5   -2  10  25  30
```